# How to optimize SQL query performance using Row_Number() to operate on millions of records in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my project, i am using the following query with paging mechanism using Row_Number() in SQL Server 2005 to fetch the records from database containing millions of records. When i execute this query it is taking almost 1:25+ seconds to fetch the results, i am unable to figure out where am i going wrong ? How can we optimize this query to bring the expected results in quick possible time, displaying n records on first page and fetching respective records as paging operation proceeds ?

This is how we create table:

```
CREATE TABLE [iftable] (
    [sid] [float] DEFAULT (0) NOT NULL ,
    [mid] [float] DEFAULT (0) NOT NULL ,
    [bid] [float] DEFAULT (0) NOT NULL ,
    [fid] [float] DEFAULT (0) NOT NULL ,
    [fsid] [float] DEFAULT (0) NOT NULL ,
    [ftep] [float] DEFAULT (0) NOT NULL ,
    [mtid] [float] DEFAULT (0) NOT NULL ,
    [mstr] [varchar] (1000) DEFAULT (' ') NOT NULL ,
    [urblb] [image] NULL ,
    [urcode] [float] DEFAULT (0) NOT NULL ,
    [cdate] [datetime] DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL ,
    [ctime] [char] (9) DEFAULT (' ') NOT NULL ,
    [olevel] [float] DEFAULT (0) NOT NULL,
    [cat] [varchar](30) DEFAULT (' ') NOT NULL,
    [ukey1] [varchar](30) DEFAULT (' ') NOT NULL,
    [ukey2] [varchar](30) DEFAULT (' ') NOT NULL,
    [vk] [varchar](30) DEFAULT (' ') NOT NULL,
    [scode] [float] DEFAULT (0)  NOT NULL,
    [sty] [float] DEFAULT (0)  NOT NULL,
    [extnsn] [varchar](10) DEFAULT ('') NOT NULL,
    [pkey] [varchar] (30) DEFAULT (' ') NOT NULL,
    [bexists] [smallint] DEFAULT (0) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE  UNIQUE  INDEX [iftablekey01] ON [iftable]([pkey], [sid], [mid]) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

//Select query over the table created

```
DECLARE @Sid nvarchar(30) 
DECLARE @Bid nvarchar(30) 
DECLARE @Fid nvarchar(30) 
DECLARE @Stid nvarchar(30) 
DECLARE @QFid nvarchar(30) 
DECLARE @FromDate nvarchar(30) 
DECLARE @ToDate nvarchar(30) 
DECLARE @RFID nvarchar(30) 
DECLARE @FRID nvarchar(30) 
DECLARE @FsID nvarchar(30) 
DECLARE @Exclude nvarchar(MAX) 
DECLARE @ExecuteDSQL nvarchar(MAX) 

--Here below all the values will be coming from different variables like @QFid = 'VarQfid'

SET @Sid = '' IF(@Sid = '*') SET @Sid = 'ALL' 
SET @Bid = '' IF(@Bid = '*') SET @Bid = 'ALL' 
SET @Fid = '' IF(@Fid = '*') SET @Fid = 'ALL' 
SET @Stid = '' IF(@Stid = '*') SET @Stid = 'ALL' 
SET @QFid = 'ALL' 
SET @FromDate = '' 
SET @ToDate = '' 
SET @RFID = '' 
SET @FRID = '' 
SET @FsID = '' 
SET @Exclude = '' IF(@Exclude = '') SET @Exclude = '100'

SET @ExecuteDSQL = 'SELECT * FROM ( SELECT *, Row_Number() over(order by cdate desc,ctime desc,mid desc) as rowNum from iftable where pkey=''ABC''' 

+ 

' AND (cdate BETWEEN (CASE WHEN '''+@FromDate+''' =''0'' THEN ''1970-01-01'' WHEN '''+@FromDate+''' = '''' THEN ''1970-01-01'' ELSE ''ValueCameFromVariable'' END) AND (CASE WHEN '''+@ToDate+''' = ''0'' THEN ''5000-01-01'' WHEN '''+@ToDate+''' = '''' THEN ''5000-01-01'' ELSE ''ValueCameFromVariable'' END)) ' 

+ 

' AND (('''+@QFid+''' = ''ALL'' AND mtid IN (select mtid FROM iftable)) OR ('''+@QFid+''' = ''Err'' AND mtid IN(9,15)) OR ('''+@QFid+''' = ''CLog'' AND mtid IN(9,15,14,50,56))) ' 

+ 

' AND sid = (CASE WHEN '''+@Sid+''' = ''ALL'' THEN sid WHEN '''+@Sid+''' = '''' THEN sid ELSE '''+@Sid+''' END) ' 

+ 

' AND bid = (CASE WHEN '''+@Bid+''' = ''ALL'' THEN bid WHEN '''+@Bid+''' = '''' THEN bid ELSE '''+@Bid+''' END) ' 

+ 

' AND fid = (CASE WHEN '''+@Fid+''' = ''ALL'' THEN fid WHEN '''+@Fid+''' = '''' THEN fid ELSE '''+@Fid+''' END) ' 

+ 

' AND stid = (CASE WHEN '''+@Stid+''' = ''ALL'' THEN stid WHEN '''+@Stid+''' = '''' THEN stid ELSE '''+@Stid+''' END)' 

+ 

' AND rfid = (CASE WHEN '''+@RFID+''' = ''0'' THEN rfid WHEN '''+@RFID+''' = '''' THEN rfid ELSE '''+@RFID+''' END) ' 

+ 

' AND frid = (CASE WHEN '''+@FRID+''' = ''0'' THEN frid WHEN '''+@FRID+''' = '''' THEN frid ELSE '''+@FRID+''' END) ' 

+ 

' AND fsid = (CASE WHEN '''+@FsID+''' = ''0'' THEN fsid WHEN '''+@FsID+''' = '''' THEN fsid ELSE '''+@FsID+''' END)' 

+ 

' AND mtid NOT IN ('+@Exclude+')) AS newTable WHERE newTable.RowNum BETWEEN ''1'' AND ''50''' 

exec sp_executesql @ExecuteDSQL
```

Comment: I think its a problem of indexes. can u post the SQL Query of table creation, and indexes?

Comment: @Tirma, yes sure i will...

Comment: @Tirma, please take a look, i have modified question.

Comment: your case statement seems to be wrong, Can you please correct your case statement in you query. You can use print in place of exec to generate static query.

Comment: @IndraPrakashTiwari, this is perfectly working query.

Comment: First off - [don't use `BETWEEN`, especially with date/time/timestamp types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), since it's probably giving you incorrect results.  Next, you should change the way the statement is generated to completely remove clauses if they don't do any work.  Since you're already doing dynamic SQL this isn't much of a change.  It should also make your explain plans cleaner.  What version of SQL Server?  2012 supports `OFFSET`/`LIMIT`, which would remove the need for `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your Query is you are sorting by cdate desc,ctime desc,mid 
but you dont have indexes by all the columns your are using to sort.

You should create this index to improve your query:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [_dta_index_iftable_c_8_205243786__K11D_K12D_K2D] ON [dbo].[iftable] 
(
    [cdate] DESC,
    [ctime] DESC,
    [mid] DESC
)WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: One more thing....
instead of build an string into the variable ExecuteDSQL   and then call sp_executesql,   i think its much better to execute the query directly.

just as an example, instead of using 
SET ExecuteDSQL = 'SELECT * FROM A'
exec sp_executesql ExecuteDSQL

just use    select * from A   
It will work!!

Comment: ,It is working perfect in SQL Server Management Studio but taking  a lot more time from browser.